# HorizontalScrollView considers only first child of nested ListView

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have a `ListView` thats nested inside a `HorizontalScrollView` like so:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:fillViewport="true">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In the `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` method I dynamically add `TextViews` and `ImageViews`. The underlying data gets set once in the `ListActivity`'s `onCreate()` method. If the width of one list item exceeds the available space the `ScrollView` does not scroll, unless it's the first item and the View scrolls only until the right border of the first item is visible.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ListView's layout_height value to fill_parent.